# Adding Static Cells to UITableView Dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating a simple sign up/login screen. I am using static cells as follows:

[image]

The cells are static. I want that when I click the sign up button I add 2 more cells to the tableview. Is that possible considering that I am using static cells and not dynamic?

UPDATE:

I am trying to set the height to 0.0f inside the heightForRowAtIndexPath but it is blowing up.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // this line 

    if(cell.tag == 2)
        return 0.0f;

    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: Why does this even need to be a UITableView?

Comment: You can easily implement this using just a UIScrollView and some simple animations.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the table  and it asks for the size you would add 2 more to it.  Just based on the row index you would decide to use the static cells or whatever else you are inserting.

Comment: How would you add two more to it? I am using designer storyboards.

Comment: You would have to leave the confines of the storyboard  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but it appears that you have 2 cells in the image. That means you're trying to go from 2 to 4 cells once your signup code has run. Simply put the 4 static cells in your storyboard UITableView and implement the following method and call `[self reloadData]` to trigger it:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (SIGNUP_CODE_HAS_RUN == YES)
    {
        // where SIGNUP_CODE_HAS_RUN is set to YES after you've run your signup code
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```